# What is really happening when the applet window size is changed by the user?

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, thread-sleep

Whenever I drag to change the window size in my applet, the paint method appears to run again. What is really happening? Is the paint method just re-running itself? Is there a way I can make it do this automatically (without changing the window size)? The for loop does not seem to be working. I had a thread.sleep method in the code but it still didn't help. I will include the code for the paint method below.

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
// Paints the stick figures on the applet.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
public void paint(Graphics page) {
    // for (int f = 0; f < 6; f++) {

    resize(400, 150);
    for (int u = 0; u < stickdudes.length; u++)
        stickdudes[u].draw(page);

    // Delay.sleep(3000);
    // }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about invoking `paint` or how to implement it?

Comment: I know how to invoke and implement it. I want to know how to automatically run it again.

Comment: you can use the repaint() method to call the paint method again :)

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad! Put this as an answer so I can credit you.

Comment: Thanks I am happy to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to call the `paint()` method again and again the `repaint()` method is used both in AWT and Swing

Answer (score 2):

From [Painint in AWT and Swing: AWT Painting Guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#awt_summary),

> Programs may trigger a future call to `paint()` by invoking `repaint()`, but shouldn't call `paint()` directly.